# Google Apps Script date format

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, logging

I have this wonderful piece of working code to sent e-mails on my behalf:

```
function sentEmails() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AUTO").activate();
var lr = ss.getLastRow()
var Mailtemplate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Mailtemplate").getRange(1,1).getValue();
for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++){
var currentMember = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
var currentExpire = ss.getRange(i, 8).getValue();
var subjectLine = "Your membership " + currentSubjectSuffix;
var messageBody = Mailtemplate.replace("{text}",currentText)
.replace("{member}",currentMember)
.replace("{expire}",currentExpire)
Logger.log(Mailtemplate);
}
```

But the date sent is "Thu Sep 07 2023 05:00:00 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)" while I just want it to be 07/09/2023.

How can this be done?

Comment: Code is incomplete

Comment: I changed it. I think I cut to much before for the sample purpose

Comment: This was already asked multiple times... instead of getValue try getDisplayValue or use Utilities.formatDate or use new Intl.DateTimeFormat().format(date).

Comment: var currentExpire = ss.getRange(i, 8).getDisplayValue(); worked. 
Thank you to both of you.